# Mandatory field indicator in Jenkins TextBox or checkbox

Tags: jenkins

Is there any way where i can define a mandatory * ( asterix ) for a field in jenkins some thing like red colored star. I am using a text after the field saying it mandatory. can i use some indication like star with color to indicate mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure Global Security**, and change the **Markup Formatter** selection from *Plain Text* to *Safe HTML* then click **Apply**.

Go back to configuring the job, and in the **Description** box, you can CSS in a span tag. For example: `<span style="color: red;">This is a mandatory field.</span>`

Comment: Excellent, this is what i need. I cant upvote this as i have no reputations. But this is what i need and thank you very much